# Can I use standard tools to get the full name of a process, when its name has embedded spaces?

Tags: bash, process, filename

I understand that it may be a rare situation for an executable to have spaces in it, but it could happen.

An example may be the best explanation..

Using standard tools, I want to determine the location (on the file system) of the executable which owns(?) the current window...

1. get the current window ID ...(`xdotool` getactivewindow )
2. use the ID to get the PID ...(`wmctrl` -p -l | sed ... ID ....
3. use the PID to get the executable's name ... (`ps` -A ... **here** is where I run into problems !

Whith `ps`, when listing only the executable's name (`-o ucmd`), it truncates the name to 15 characters, so this rules out this option for any name which is longer.
Widening the column  (`-o ucmd:99` ) makes no difference.. If `pgrep` is anything to go by, its matching is limited to 15 because of `stat` (see: info pgrep)..

Listings in variants of "full" mode (eg `-A w w`) are not useful when the name concerned has spaces in it, because this name is separated from its args by *another space*!..  Also, in "full" mode, if the process was started by a link, the name of the link is shown, rather than the executable's name.

Is there some way to do this (using standard tools)? ...or are spaces a show stopper here?

Comment: I am not sure this can be classified as standard: cat "/proc/$PID/cmdline" |cut -d "" -f1

Comment: It's looking very interesting, but nautilus has bogged down while trying to load 58,000 files in /proc (Is that normal to have that many there; what are they all doing?)... and I believe ti is absolutely standard... It is as standard as passing data from an email cliendt to a Word Processor, then including some pics you tweaked in a picture tweaker, adding an audio clip you prepared, and a spreadsheet thrown in.. Acatually I prefer the simple stuff like `ls` and `grep`.... :)   GUI stuff is too complicated ...

Comment: This gives me what I'm after `readlink -e /proc/$PID/exe`.. the executable's full path... but I don't know enough about proc (yet) to know if this works consistantly... Also as is the case with a with good answer as a comment; it leave the question "hanging".. so João, could you adapt this comment to an answer.. I like it.. it is as simple as `ls` ... no spreadsheet formulas(ae?) to deal with.. :)

Comment: (ammended comment)  **/proc/$PID/cmdline** does extract the name with any spaces includes, and when that name is a link, then **`readlink -e "$(cat "/proc/9577/cmdline"|cut -d "" -f1)"`** tracks down the exe...  (and it's  good to know you an `cut` at a null :)

Comment: **NB.**.. For anyone reading this, please note that the **cut** method does **not** work with null (it *appears* to work... see more detailed comments in the comment section of Gilles answer....

Comment: basename $(readlink /proc/$PID/exename)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All utilities get their information from `/proc/$PID` anyway, but there are (at least) three places in `/proc/$PID` that contain the name of the executable in some form, and they report different information.

- The `Name` field in `/proc/$PID/status` (also available in a harder-to-parse form in `/proc/$PID/stat`). This is the name of the executable, but truncated to 15 characters. Since the kernel performs the truncation, no option to `ps` can help. That's what `ps -o comm` (or its synonym `ps -o ucmd`) shows.
- The symbolic link `/proc/$PID/exename` point to the executable file. You can get its contents with **`readlink /proc/$PID/exename`**. Unlike the information reported by `ps`, only the user running the process has permission to read the link target.
- The zeroth argument to the process, as chosen by the shell or other program that invoked it. By convention, shells choose the name of the executable as you typed it (with or without a full path). You can get all the arguments from `ps` with `ps -o cmd` (or its synonym `ps -o command`), but the arguments are separated by spaces so you can't reliably tell where the zeroth argument stops. You can read the arguments from `/proc/cmdline`, where they are separated by null character: **`</proc/$PID/cmdline awk -vRS='\0' '{print; exit;}'`** extracts the zeroth argument.

For completeness, let me mention that these names can change during the lifetime of the process, though most programs don't do it:

- The process can change `Name` field of `/proc/$PID/status` by calling [`prctl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/prctl.2.html) with the `PR_SET_NAME` argument.
- The executable file can be renamed or deleted. In simple cases, Linux keeps track of the new name (but edge cases might not work, e.g. if you make a hard link to the executable). If the file is deleted, the kernel adds `(deleted)` to the link target.
- The zeroth argument to the process is read from process memory (it's `argv[0]` in C). The process can modify it freely.

Comment: This explanation works better than my solution.  Try: which "$(readlink /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getactivewindow))/exe)"

Comment: @fred.bear: Thanks for spotting this. Both `tr` commands are meant to swap newlines with nulls. `head` extracts the first line; the whole tr/head/tr pipe extracts the first null-terminated chunk. In this particular case, the second `tr` command could be `tr '\0' '\n'` since there's a single chunk left.

Comment: @Gilles.. Thanks! another mystery unwravelled... very well explained.... (btw.. It seems the typo gremlim struck again...the first `tr` args  should be `\\0 \\n`)...  and thanks for the bonus insight: ..obfiscate the trailing newline by nulling it out... (I'm not sure how bash handles nulls.. I suppose I can use '-d \\n' until I have a fuller understanding) ....  and another bonus (by example)... not using 'cat' when '<' does the job... I read someone's blog tirrade about that ,and such things, the other day (by a  Randal Schwartz (perhaps the one from 'FLOSS Weekly'...:)

Comment: Just for the record :), because I need it as a var, I'm going with: `cmd="$(</proc/10773/cmdline cut -d '' -f1)"` ...

Comment: @fred.bear: `cut` alone won't work in the rare case when the string to extract contains a newline.

Comment: Noted... thanks... I tested it... Regardless of any pre-existing newline chars (which remain uneffected), it replaces the '\0' with a newline (ie, an extra one) and truncates the rest...  The result is a trailing newline char which wasn't there beforehand.... I see now why you did it  your way.. *experience!* :) ...

Comment: @fred.bear: Actually, `head` keeps the newline at the end of the first line, and the second `tr` changes it to a spurious null character. Oops again. Oh well, I've changed it to use awk, which can be told to use a different record separator: I tell it to print the first null-delimited record (with a trailing newline, but the shell will strip that in `$(…)`) and exit.

Comment: Gilles. You've resolved the issue very nicely/ Thanks for that... As a side issue, I've time tested 3 ways of extracting the command name from /proc/$PID/cmdline. I'm posting them for general interest (and comment if any are flawed :)...  For 10000 calls, the times varied from 31.8s to 33.0 ..... (1) **`cmd="$(</proc/$PID/cmdline awk -vRS='\0' '{print; exit;}')"`** ..... (2) **`eval cmd=\""$(</proc/$PID/cmdline sed -n "s/\x00/\"\n#/gp")"`** ..... (3) **`cmd="$(</proc/$PID/cmdline tr \\0 \\n)"; cmd="${cmd%%$'\n'*}"`**

Comment: @fred.bear: Only (1) works if there's a newline in argv[0]. `cmd=$(cat /proc/$PID/cmdline); cmd=${cmd%%$'\0'}` works in ksh, but not in bash.

Comment: Thanks again... It's been a lot of effort all around on this one.. I do greatly appreaciate the help.. I feel I've made another step.. (not sure where I'm going with my steps, but it's a fascinating journey) .. and I'll be watching out more carefully for those pesky "what are they doing there?" newlines from here on :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ps $PID | tail -1 | awk '{i=5; while (i<NF) {printf "%s ", $i; i++}; print $NF}'
```

Where $PID is the PID you have. Probably the full command you want (based on your question above) is:

```
which "$(ps $(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getactivewindow)) | tail -1 | awk '{i=5; while (i<NF) {printf "%s ", $i; i++}; print $NF}')"
```

Comment: .. Up to a certain point, your solution works. However my question relates to **beyond** that point... ie. when the command has 3 specific attributes... (1) The basename is longer than 15... (2) It has embedded spaces... (3) There are Args... eg. In /usr/bin make a link: **`'Link to gedit with spaces'`**... Run this link with the Arg **`'test file'`**... Then get its PID... Then the command portion of `ps $PID` returns this: **`/usr/bin/Link to gedit with spaces test file`** ... As you can see this `ps` output is not parsable.. Where do the Args  begin? ...

Comment: Yeah, I understand now.  Sorry!  See my comment on Gilles's solution below.

Comment: I finally got around to testing your suggestion (in Gille's comment).. Again, it works, but only up to a point; a *different* point this time... As Gille's mentions in his 2nd point (about /proc/$PID/exe). **"only the user running the process has permission to read the link target."** ... The 3rd method he mentions, is however accessible.... eg. I, as a "user", cannot access a roo owned target of "../exe", but I can access a root owned "../cmdline"... (It certainly has been an interesting little journey. ;)
 PS Thanks for pointing out xdotools **getwindowpid**.. I'd missed that one completely~

Comment: Hmmm.  That's true, I suppose.  I had assumed (bad thing to do!) that you would own the active window; I guess there are cases (e.g. Synaptic) where that's not the case.  Sorry.